# Check if an element exists in XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

XML:

```
<CONFIGURATION>
<Files>
    <File>D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder1\TestFile.txt</File>
    <File>D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder1\TestFile01.txt</File>
    <File>D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder1\TestFile02.txt</File>
    <File>D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder1\TestFile03.txt</File>
    <File>D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder1\TestFile04.txt</File>
</Files>
<SizeMB>3</SizeMB>
<BackupLocation>D:\Log backups\File backups</BackupLocation>
</CONFIGURATION>
```

Code:

```
private void btnLinq_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        queryData(@"D:\WatchMe1\backupconfig1.xml");
    }

static void queryData(string xmlFile)
    {
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
        var configuration = xdoc.Element("CONFIGURATION");
        string sizeMB = configuration.Element("SizeMB").Value;
        string backupLocation = configuration.Element("BackupLocation").Value;
        //need a code here to check if element <File> exist before executing the file array
        string[] files = configuration.Element("Files").Elements("File").Select(c => c.Value).ToArray();

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }
    }
```

I have an xml writer program that edits the above xml. The Files element can be changed to Folder element. I have another program that reads the values(file locations) and do something with it, I have to check first if the element is a Files or Folders element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if XML Element exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101145/check-if-xml-element-exists)

Comment: I don't know if I understood you but when you try to check if an element contains any elements, try this: bool check = myXml.Elements("nameOfElement").Any(). You can also read the element and check if it's null or not.

Comment: @BigYellowCactus: He is not using the Xpath approach. He wants to use Linq. So maybe its not a duplicate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check for element existence with something like

```
if(configuration.Elements("...").Any()){...}
```

But i'm not sure what you are asking here exactly...

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want to do:

```
if(configutation.Elements.First("Files") != null)
{
    string[] files = configuration.Element("Files").Elements("File").Select(c => c.Value).ToArray();
}
```

Hope this helps!