# Check if xml element exists (no child nodes)

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, linq-to-xml

I want to check if a xml element with a certain value exists. Found many examples but these all have multiple child nodes but mine doesn't.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<data>
<cocktail>1</cocktail>
<cocktail>2</cocktail>
<cocktail>3</cocktail>
</data>
```

C#: (the variable `name` contains the value for which I want to check whether it exists or not)

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream, LoadOptions.None);
bool b = (from cocktail in doc.Root.Elements("data") 
     where (bool)cocktail.Name.Equals(name) select cocktail).Any();
```

Comment: So you just want to know whether a "cocktail" element exists? Why not simply use SelectXmlNodes(".//cocktail") and check the count?

Comment: ok, maybe I wasn't clear but I want to check if the element `cocktail` exists, with the `value` which is stored in `name`

Comment: Typical mistake with your use of `doc.Root.Elements("data")`, as doc.Root is already the `data` element. Just got bitten by that one myself.

Comment: you can check this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101145/check-if-xml-element-exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't completely clear, but assuming you want to know whether the root element has a `<cocktail>` child with value `name`, this would work:

```
bool exists = doc.Root.Elements("cocktail")
    .Where(element => element.Value == name)
    .Any();
```

Comment: I too prefer working with the Fluent API rather than with Query Expressions