# Test is a node exists in the XML FILE

Tags: c#, xml

How Can I test in C# if a node exists in an XML FILE ?

I read my xmlfile like these :

```
 XmlDocument docxml = new XmlDocument();
 docxml.LoadXml("test.xml");
 XmlNode root = docxml.DocumentElement;
```

And I want to test if a particular node exists in my file.

How can I do that ?

Comment: See [Check if xml element exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101145/check-if-xml-element-exists).

Answer (score 0):

```
   XmlDocument tourdetailsxml = new XmlDocument();
                XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml");
                tourdetailsxml.Load(xmlReader);
                var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(tourdetailsxml.InnerXml);
                var Error = xdoc.Descendants("Error").ToList();
                for(var i = 0; i < Error.Count(); i++){

                }
```

Comment: It's easier and faster to use XPath